# No Internet detection jQuery isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have got a problem with my jQuery code which supposed to detect connectivity to the internet.

```
function checkConnection() {
var connected = true;
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = "https://p5-zbjpil5uzqzqg-b5icu4xm7kglqch5-458861-i2-v6exp3-ds.metric.gstatic.com/v6exp3/6.gif";
img.onerror = function () {
    connected = false;
};
return connected;
}
setInterval(function () {
var isConnected = checkConnection(); // checkConnection() comes from above code
if (isConnected) {
    alert('internet');
} else {
    alert('no internet');
}
}, 3000);
```

It doesn't matter wheater I am online or offline there is the same alert window INTERNET comes up. Can you please help to fix the code? The fiddle is available below, feel free to amend it.

http://jsfiddle.net/yV28D/2/

Many thanks.

Comment: Your return is happening before the onerror happens, resulting in it always returning true. Welcome to asynchronous programming!

Comment: Hi Kevin. Thank you for your advice. Can you please help me to fix it?

Comment: Alert in the onError / onSuccess handlers? And this is javaSCRIPT, not Java. Different language and platform entirely.

Comment: I updated the fiddle in your question to one that is far less annoying and far easier to work with

Comment: Just wanted to throw this out there for you to think about. Just because the image doesn't load properly doesn't necessarily mean you are not connected. If your image ever gets moved/removed, this test will fail. However, the client may still be connected to the internet. It seems like a very low level test to conduct with a large possibility for error.

Comment: Hi War10ck, I agree with you. But navigator.onLine failed a few times when I tried to use it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When dealing with events, you typically want to use callbacks.

http://jsfiddle.net/yV28D/3/

```
function checkConnection(callback) {
    var img = document.createElement('img');    
    img.onerror = function () {
        callback(false);
    };
    img.onload = function() {
        callback(true);
    };
    img.src = "https://p5-zbjpil5uzqzqg-b5icu4xm7kglqch5-458861-i2-v6exp3-ds.metric.gstatic.com/v6exp3/6.gif";
}
setInterval(function () {
    checkConnection(function(isConnected){
        if (isConnected) {
            console.log('internet');
        } else {
           console.log('no internet');
        }
    }); // checkConnection() comes from above code
}, 3000);
```

Otherwise, you will always get `true` because the return is happening before the error callback has a chance to be executed.

Also, when dealing with onload and onerror events, you always want to bind the events before you set the src, otherwise it's possible for the event to happen before you bind to it.

Comment: Hi Kevin, is there any way to prevent caching the image?

Comment: Yes, add `$.now()` to it. `img.src = theurl + "?_=" + $.now()`